# Example of DNS Compression Pointer Offset > than 12 bytes

Tags: pointers, dns, compression

I want to write my own DNS server as an experiment to learn more about DNS. I've been reading RFC 1035 and it mentions a DNS Compression Pointer used in the answers of DNS replies.

I read that the compression pointer offset starts from the transaction ID (beginning of response) and goes on until it finds the host name in the question section of the response.

Since the DNS header is 12 bytes long, every request I've sent has had an offset of 12. Can anyone provide an example of when the offset would be greater than 12?

Answer (score 1):

Prior occurence of the same name can sometimes be only the last part of the previous domain name:

(Example from [Wireshark SampleCaptures, mDNS & Apple Rendezvous](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures#mDNS_.26_Apple_Rendezvous), mDNS3.cap)

[image]